# <H2> text is not appearing in google chrome browser

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript code for generating event click print preview, then in print preview I unable to get `<H2>` text, while `<h1>` text is appearing in the output html5 on google chrome but `<H2>` text is not appearing in the print preview chrome browser, Please guide and suggest me

Thanks in advance!

**Input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pat>
    <title>Main Title is Here</title>
    <body>
        <section>
            <title>section title is here</title>
            <p>Content is here</p>
        </section>
        <section><title>section title is here</title>
            <p>content is here</p>
        </section>
    </body>
</pat>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
function contentWindowPrint(){
var getiframeurl = document.getElementById('contentwin');
if(location)
{
if(location.protocol == "file:")
{
printIframe(getiframeurl.src, window.iframeHeight.height);
}
else{
getiframeurl.contentWindow.window.print()
}
}
}

function printIframe(url, height) {
var heading_one = window.iframeHeight.heading
var proxyIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.appendChild(proxyIframe);
proxyIframe.style.width = '100%';
proxyIframe.style.height = '100%';
proxyIframe.style.display = 'none';


var contentWindow = proxyIframe.contentWindow;
contentWindow.document.open();

var is_chrome = Boolean(contentWindow.chrome);
contentWindow.document.write("<h2>" + heading_one +"</h2>")
contentWindow.document.write('<iframe src="' + url + '" onload="print();" width="1450" height="' + (height + 700) + '" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>');
contentWindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10 and necessary before onload for chrome

if (is_chrome) {
contentWindow.onload = function() { // wait until all resources loaded 
};
}
else {
contentWindow.document.write('<iframe src="' + url + '" onload="print();" width="1450" height="' + (height + 700) + '" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>');
contentWindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10 and necessary before onload for chrome
}

return true;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
$("div.ditasearch > input").val('')
$("div.ditasearchHeader > input").val('')
});
```

Comment: [<title>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) is for the `<head>`. It is not a tag to use for titles in general. You can use like `h2` and style it.

Comment: Thanks @Peter Krebs, yes I am styling in the output <H2>, but not showing in the print preview, please suggest

Comment: Please help and suggest me regarding above issue

Comment: I meant don't use `<title>` in your original HTML. Otherwise what is the CSS for the print view? Can you make your code a runnable snippet with the `<>` button? Hard to tell otherwise why text would disappear.

Comment: Thanks @PeterKrebs, Still <H2> content is not appearing in the print preview

Comment: Okay sure. Have you read what I wrote? Also post your CSS and make your code a working snippet with the `<>` button. If HTML and JS works then we have to look at the styling.